# EditText line is not visible and does not change colour

Tags: android, colors, android-edittext, styles, output

So for a while now, I've been tried to fix the issue I've been having with the EditText field, as it does not show the single line under where the Hint or actual text would go. Typically, the line would be black by default, so my question is this; how do I enable the line to show up again, as well as how do I change the colour of it? (I would assume android:backgroundHint would do the trick however I just cannot see the line at all so cannot test it). I am using API 24/25.

Below is a sample of my XML code as well as the emulator output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_register"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.michael.whatsupldn.RegisterActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

  <EditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:hint="Name"
      android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[Emulator Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dc9Y.png)

My styles.xml code

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="EditTextTheme">
    <!-- Used for the bottom line when not selected / focused -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#FAFAFA</item>
    <!-- colorControlActivated & colorControlHighlight use the colorAccent         color by default -->
</style>

</resources>
```

My colors.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="colorRadioButton">#f5f5f5</color>
    <color name="yellow1">#ffff00</color>
    <color name="yellow2">#ffEA00</color>
    <color name="grey05">#F5F5F5</color>
    <color name="orange4">#FFB74D</color>
    <color name="orange5">#FFA726</color>
    <color name="blue2">#f5f5f5</color>
    <color name="blue25">#fafafa</color>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code, Add your theme code.

Comment: @W4R10CK I have now added it

Comment: try to change the theme from the preview section.

Comment: Can you add the `colors.xml` file?

Comment: @luian Popescu I have now added the file, please take a look

Comment: @W4R10CK How do you mean from the previous version?

Comment: @z3n105 Would you know why I may be having this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextAddress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapWords"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bottom_border"
    android:hint="Address">

// edit_text_bottom_border.xml          

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/r...">
    <item
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="-3dp"
        android:right="-3dp"
        android:top="-3dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#000" />

            <solid android:color="#00ffffff" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: If I had more than one EditText, would I have the layer-list after each one, e.g. EditText, LayerList, Edit,Text, LayerList or would the LayerList be defined at the bottom of the XML page?

Comment: create the edit_text_bottom_border.xml file inside drawable folder inside res folder and set background of edittext, there is no need to write layer-list code inside layout file.

Answer (score 5):

Change `backgroundTint` from **white** to some other dark color in the `edittext` in your xml layout file and change your theme for the activity

Please Refer this link: http://www.codexpedia.com/android/setting-edittext-underline-color-in-android/

Comment: any reason for down voting

Comment: Have you checked this

Comment: not work with android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

Comment: I knew that you were talk about edittext,☺☺☺
That the reason for down vote ... (not by me)

Answer (score 2):

Change Height to **wrap_content**

```
<EditText
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:hint="Name"
  android:layout_margin="16dp"/>
```

Comment: changing the height to `wrap_content` does not do anything new, its already `match_parent` which is matching parent height.

Comment: @W4R10CK Yes exactly, my height is already wrap_conent and width is match_parent meaning is should display horizontally to match the linear layout, yet nothin displays

Answer (score 1):

**Remove the below line from your layout file(if already exists)**

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_register"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.michael.whatsupldn.RegisterActivity">

 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
           <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Underline color change"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
            <requestFocus/>
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't changed anything for me.

Comment: so can you tell me, what is actually happening ?

Comment: @diwn.dhanvani As I have explained above, the line which is supposed to be underneath an EditText field, is not displaying

Comment: Try this :    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Underline color change"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light" />

Comment: I had edit the answer. so you can try this. in my app this is showing a red line below the hint text. @MichaelDybek